# how can i mirror phone screen with a brocken black screen?

Tags: backup

my phone fell a few times and alas the screen is now unfunctional. there is a line straight down the middle, on one side it is black and on the other, it is purple/white/green, my point, that I cant use it for anything.

now, how can I mirror my screen onto another device so that I can backup everything I have on my device and be able to transfer it (and also still be able to use my old device until/)when I get a new device.

USB debugging is already activated on my phone but whenever I try to adb, I am told that I need to grant permission on my phone (which of course is impossible, being that I have no access to my screen).

now, I understand that I can purchase an external screen and connect it to my device via usb c and I don't need to go through this whole hocus pocus of usb debugging and screen mirroring, rather it can connect automatically, but that requires me to purchase a screen, etc.

is there any way I can do that exact same thing with a screen that I already have at how, for example, my laptop screen, or maybe I just got this whole thing wrong?

If you cant help me with the above, then please help me with this, how can I back up my data. i downloaded dr.fone, but the doctor broke the news to me that he can't help my phone if i don't permit him to do so, which will require me to grant permission on my phone.

or any other option for me to acquire my data thank you!!

p.s. i am running windows 10 20h2 and Linux mint.

Comment: The number of phones that support external screens is not very high. You can try USB-C to DisplayPort or HDMI connectors and try it out. But even if it works input is still the problem. USB mouse and keyboard can be connected but usually not at the same time as the monitor adapter.  Another problem is that the ADB authorization dialog is only shown while the USB connection to your PC is established. If you disconnect the PC connection (e.g. to switch to an USB keyboard) the authorization dialog also closes.